# Number of homomorphisms between G TO/INTO/ONTO G'

Tags: group-theory

How many homomorphisms are between following groups:

Type 1. $Z_{10}$ to $Z_{10}$

Type 2. $ Z$ to $Z_{10}$

Type 3. $ Z$  onto $Z $

Type 4. $ Z $ into $ Z $

Type 5. $Z$ into $Z_2 $

These type of questions seem quite important to me and so far I can only solve the first type. The general case of type 1 is the number of homomorphisms of $ Z_m TO Z_n $ is gcd(m, n). Also in cyclic domain homomorphism is completly determined by image of generator, which I read somewhere, but what difference is between type 1, type 3 and type 4 where we have TO in type1, ONTO in type 3 and INTO in type 4. How to deal with them.

problems of type 2,3,4,5 are still critical issues for me. Is there a complete way to deal with such sort of problemz.

Comment: You stated the necessary property - that homomorphisms are determined by the image of generators. So take the type 2 problem, for example. What is the generator(s) for Z? How many places can you map it?

Comment: Z has 2 generators and Z_10 has 4 generators. Can you explain further?

Comment: So for any particular generator of Z, to where can you map that generator in $Z_{10}$ to define a homomorphism?

Comment: $\phi (1) $=1, $\phi (1)$=3,$\phi (1) $=7 and $\phi (1) $ =9. Should be the 4 distinct homomorphisms.